# Can one escape from the "mirror-image" of Russell's Paradox?

Tags: set-theory

Let s denote the "virtual set" (x:x is an element of x). Does there exist a set
theory T (based on classical logic and not so far proved inconsistent) such
that: (1) T allows the existence of all the sets in ZF as well as many infinite
self-membered sets. (2) T allows s to exist as an actual set and provides an
answer to the question "Is s an element of s?" without engendering any paradox.

Comment: Wouldn't s model T and thus make T inconsistent?

Comment: If your theory also allows for V = {x : x = x} then it cannot be closed under relative complements. That's a little odd but I don't see much problems if all your instances of comprehension are positive and quantifier-free (existential quantifiers might be fine too).

Comment: I had posted a now-deleted answer explaining that all the classical set theories prove that your set s exists and is empty, since under the Foundation axiom no set is a member of itself, so the set of x with x in x is empty. (Gowers, in your comment you were missing a "not" in this argument). But now that I read your question more closely (as Nate Eldredge pointed out), the second clause of (1) rules out these theories. 

Comment: Garabed, could you clarify what you mean by (1), since as I have pointed out, ZF proves that your set s is empty, which violates the second clause of (1). So what exactly do you mean? 

Comment: I second Joel, and I moreover ask for a more precise form for the phrase "all the sets in ZF."

Comment: The theory T that I am seeking should allow the existence of all the
sets that are allowed to exist in ZF, but not all the axioms of ZF
can be axioms of T. The Axiom of Foundation, in particular, cannot be an axiom of T, since it would not allow s to be non-empty. I think of T as a theory somewhat resembling Quine's "New Foundations"
-although "New Foundations" itself could not, of course, allow s to
exist since then the "RUssell set" which is the complement of s
would also exist and we would have an outright inconsistency.

Comment: To focus your question somewhat, I think you should just say that you want T to contain ZF-Foundation. I can't make precise sense of your proposal that T "should allow the existence of all the sets that are allowed to exist in ZF" in any other way. So my proposal is that you ask: Is it (relatively) consistent with ZF-Foundation that { x | x in x} is a nonempty set with infinite members?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a set theory. It is ZF minus foundation plus Aczel's "anti-foundation axiom".

One reference for this system is a book-length set of lecture notes by Aczel, http://standish.stanford.edu/pdf/00000056.pdf

In this theory, the collection of all sets that contain themselves is nonempty (in fact, it is a proper class) and contains elements that are themselves infinite.

<s>If you wanted the collection of all sets that contain themselves to itself be a set, you could try to restrict the anti-foundation axiom to a some particular definable set of graphs; it is usually stated for the class of all graphs.</s>

Comment: Can you prove that if you restrict the anti-Foundation axiom to a set of graphs G, that in ZF-Foudnation+AntiFoundation(G), that s is a set? Of course, it contains all the non-well-founded sets that must exist by G, but how do you know that this doesn't somehow lead to a proper class of x such that $x\in x$? 

Comment: No, I have not thought about a rigorous proof. Of course even if you limit the anti-foundation axiom, the old model of the full axiom is still a model of the limited axiom.  So it appears that some analogue of L would be needed to guarantee there are not too many sets that contain themselves.  Aczel does give a concrete class model of ZF - foundation + antifoundation, so that might be a place to start. I'll see if I can strike that part of my answer. 

Comment: My point is that under ZF-Foundation, it is conceivable that once there is a single set x with $x\in x$, then you can build from that x a proper class of such x, and in this case the answer to the question would be negative. (But I have not yet found a proof of this, and so I'm not sure.)

Comment: Hi Carl! Welcome to MO! @Joel: I think you do get something reasonable with just extensionality + AFA(G) + positive quantifier-free comprehension (which proves that the set S exists). If you take for the class of graphs G the class of all graphs in some model of ZF, then you get a reasonable interpretation of the OP's "all the sets in ZF." Of course, the problem is that the big sets like S don't have much combinatorics in this kind of theory. I doubt that you can actually throw much combinatorics on top of sets like S without running into problems.

Comment: François, is that theory consistent? But also, under this route, are you giving up on power set P(s) etc.? I would think that the OP wants P(s), Union(s), etc.

Comment: I think (but I haven't worked it out) that you can simply construct a "free model" of positive quantifier-free comprehension over a model of AFA(G). I think you run into problems if you add too many powersets, unions, pairs, etc. With too much combinatorics and too many big sets, you might be able to do too much model theory and run into problems with incompleteness. I would restrict the combinatorial axioms to small sets only.

Comment: In ZF-Foundation you can have  as many Quine atoms (sets which  are  their ownn  unique element) as you like. For example,  see Chapter IIIA of Felgner's "Models of ZF Set Theory".